# How to set a XtraReport into a GroupPanel in Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I created a Form and place GroupPanel in that Form now I created XtraReports and I tried to set that XtraReports in to that GroupPanel of that Form. I tried this code but showing error *Best Overloaded method has some invalid arguments*

```
 GroupPanel1.Controls.Clear();
 XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1 ();
 ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
 GroupPanel1.Controls.Add(report); // showing error on this line 
 report.ShowPreview();
```

This code is working fine for set a Form2 inside that GroupPanel1 of Form1

```
panelControl1.Controls.Clear();
var myForm = new ListEmployee(id);
myForm.TopLevel = false;
myForm.AutoScroll = true;
myForm.Anchor = panelControl1.Anchor;
panelControl1.Controls.Add(myForm);
myForm.Show();
```

Help me to solve this. How to set XtraReports into GroupPanel ?

Thanks in avance, Srihari

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show preview for report you need to use `DocumentViewer` control:

```
GroupPanel1.Controls.Clear();

var viewer = new DocumentViewer(); //using DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Preview
viewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
GroupPanel1.Controls.Add(viewer);

var report = new XtraReport1();
viewer.DocumentSource = report;
report.CreateDocument();
```

If you want to show designer for report you neet to use `XRDesignPanel` control:

```
GroupPanel1.Controls.Clear();

var designer = new XRDesignPanel(); //using DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner
designer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
GroupPanel1.Controls.Add(designer);

var report = new XtraReport1();
designer.OpenReport(report);
```

Comment: Good find. Seems to be new with DX Version 14.1?

Comment: @StephanKeller No, I have used both of these controls in 13.2.

Answer (score 1):

`GroupPanel1.Controls.Add()` takes as argument an instance of an object descended from the `Control` class. Since the `XtraReport` class is noct descended from the `Control` class you cannot add an XtraReport to a GroupPanel or any other element on a winform.
If you only want to show the *output* of the report in the panel you could export the report to one of the supported formats.
Since you allready use DevExpress XtraReports you could use `ExportToRtf()` if you have access to the DevExpress `RichEditControl`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering I need to show that XtraReport in Form I tried in `PrintControl1` tool but getting same error. How to show this XtraReports on **FORM** using `PrintControl` tool ?

Comment: AFAIK the PrintControl class is used to print controls, i.e. descendands of the Control class.